# Scrollable table css, how set up width in percentage?

Tags: html, css

I have table with some data, and I want to add vertical scroll to tbody [table](http://jsfiddle.net/8d1efpj3/1/) via сss.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

table tbody {
    display: block;
}

table tbody {
   overflow: auto;
   height: 50px;
}
```

But I don't know how I can create cells with fixed width in order to look like [origin-table](http://jsfiddle.net/jz2fung0/) but only with scroll bar.

What are the best practices to do this?

Comment: u want the tbody to be scrollable vertically??

Comment: try `overflow: scroll;` for your `tbody`

Comment: I have version http://jsfiddle.net/8d1efpj3/1/ with overflow property but it not solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
table tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I'm not sure why you need do this twice. Arrange as shown and depending on your min or max width and height settings you should not need to change much. If your table, or tbody exceeds your settings a horizontal scroll bar will appear. If you you simply want a very small page with no room then you will need to adjust. As far as best practices goes, visit http://www.w3c.org they will have all the best practices and this is the best place to search in my opinion.

Hope this helps!